# how to draw a background for compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to set the a container background using Canvas. In XML, we usually set background of any layout. same thing I am trying to achieve here. I tried lot of ways but didn't worked.

I tried the below one

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),

    ) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Red)) {
            Canvas(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize(),
            ) {
                val rectHeight = (size.height * 0.9f)
                val arcOffset = Offset(x = 0f, y = rectHeight)

                drawRect(
                    color = Color.Blue,
                    size = Size(width = size.width, height = rectHeight),
                )

                drawArc(
                    color = Color.Blue,
                    startAngle = 180f,
                    sweepAngle = -180f,
                    useCenter = false,
                    topLeft = arcOffset,
                )
            }

            Text(text = "Hello")
        }
    }
}
```

I want to achieve circular corner shape background from the bottom. But getting the expected output like the below ScreenShot
[image: ScreenShot].

I have some other question I tried to use draw modifier with RoundedCorner: this approach is not working.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happens because you don't take into consideration that you draw that arc inside a Rectangle, it's not visible but under the hood or other functions such as

```
drawContext.canvas.drawArc()
```

explicitly uses Rect

```
fun drawArc(
    rect: Rect,
    startAngle: Float,
    sweepAngle: Float,
    useCenter: Boolean,
    paint: Paint
)
```

Rectangle covers 10% height of the Composable while you draw arc as 5% since you draw half height.

You can fix it in 2 ways.

Increase height of rectangle to 95% while keeping arc at same height.

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun ArcSample1() {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Red)) {
        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize(),
        ) {
            val rectHeight = (size.height * 0.9f)
            val arcOffset = Offset(x = 0f, y = rectHeight)

            drawRect(
                color = Color.Blue,
                size = Size(width = size.width, height = rectHeight + size.height * 0.05f),
            )

            drawArc(
                color = Color.Blue,
                startAngle = 180f,
                sweepAngle = -180f,
                useCenter = false,
                topLeft = arcOffset,
            )
        }

        Text(text = "Hello")
    }
}
```

[image]

Or increase the height of Rectangle you draw arc in, i called it `arcHeight`, and move position of this rectangle.

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun ArcSample2() {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Red)) {
        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize(),
        ) {
            val rectHeight = (size.height * 0.9f)
            val arcHeight = (size.height - rectHeight) * 2f
            val arcOffset = Offset(x = 0f, y = size.height - arcHeight)

            drawRect(
                color = Color.Blue,
                size = Size(width = size.width, height = rectHeight),
            )

            drawArc(
                color = Color.Blue,
                startAngle = 180f,
                sweepAngle = -180f,
                useCenter = false,
                topLeft = arcOffset,
                size = Size(size.width, arcHeight)
            )
        }

        Text(text = "Hello")
    }
}
```

[image]